# How to use the glob module in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 10 different types of images in a folder. After the prediction of Images using VGG16 Module in a folder, I got some levels for those Images. How can I match those levels to the images in my folder and how can I segregate the one type of images in one folder?

Not getting anything.

```
('n04536866', 'violin', 0.98542005),
 ('n03028079', 'church', 0.35847503),
 ('n02690373', 'airliner', 0.945028),
 ('n03642806', 'laptop', 0.52074945),
```

I´m getting predictions like this, now i want to match these levels with my images and filter out the one kind of images in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

Please read some [basics](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/) about neural networks and image classification. The result of your prediction is an n-dimensional vector, where n is the number of ground truth labels, and the components of the vector are the probability for each class. So from the example above the neural network assume, that the input image which was used for this prediction has a probability of 98,54% to show a violin.